# JMeter REST API script not working over Https

Tags: jmeter, performance, rest-api

I have a JMeter script, that actually have a "HTTP Sampler" for hitting a REST API. This Rest service is running on HTTPS that is currently using "Self-Signed Certificate", but when I run my script over HTTPS protocol, it fails giving error:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException

Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection reset
```

**java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
```

> I have already imported "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt" file but
>   still it is not working on HTTPS and have also gone through this [link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder)

How to run JMeter script over SSL for performance testing REST API?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607897/jmeter-and-optional-ssl-client-certificate#answer-14693655